# How to Load multiple markers in Google Map from database using ASP.NET mvc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Using this code to retrieve data from database and display in info window of markers. problem is that it not even show the makers, but well worked on giving static data. Data are returned in Json format(**data**) and it is iterated in **for loop**, Is there any issue with loop?

> **Controller**

```
db_SafeSpotEntities2 db = new db_SafeSpotEntities2();
    public ActionResult Find()
    {
        ViewBag.ListOfDropdown = db.tb_freeslot.ToList();
        return View();
    }
    public JsonResult GetAllLocation()
    {
        var data = db.tb_freeslot.ToList();
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    public JsonResult GetAllLocationById(int id)
    {
        var data = db.tb_freeslot.Where(x => x.freeslot_id == id).SingleOrDefault();
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

> **View**

```
                <div>
                    <select class="form-control" id="selectedValue" onchange="GoLocation(this.value)">
                       <option>--Select--</option>
                        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.ListOfDropdown)
                        {
                            <option value="@item.freeslot_id">@item.sllotinfree_name</option>
                        }
                    </select>
                                   <div id="map"></div>
                <script>
              var map;
              function initMap(zoomeLevel, latDb, longDb) {
                  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                      center: { lat: latDb != null ? latDb : 10.523900, lng: longDb != null ? longDb : 76.212250 },
                      zoom: zoomeLevel != null ? zoomeLevel : 15
                  });
}
              function GoLocation(locationId) {
                  debugger;
                  $.get("/user/GetAllLocationById?id=" + locationId, function (data, status) {
                      initMap(data.Zoom, data.Lat_infree, data.Long_infree);
                      var marker = [];
                      var contentString = [];
                      var infowindow = [];
                      for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) {
                              marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                              position: { lat: data[i].Lat_infree, lng: data[i].Long_infree},
                              map: map
                          });
                          contentString[i] = '<div id="content">' +
                                              '<div id="siteNotice">' +
                                              '</div>' +'<h6 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading"><b>' + data[i].sllotinfree_name + '</b></h6>' +
                                              '<div id="bodyContent">' +
                                              '<p><b>' + data[i].car_freeslot + '</b><b>car</b>' +
                                              '<p><b>' + data[i].bike_freeslot + '</b><b>bike</b>';
                          infowindow[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                              content: contentString[i]
                          });
                          var markervalue = marker[i];
                          google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'mouseover', (function (markervalue, i) {                          return function () {
                                  infowindow[i].open(map, marker[i]);
                              }
                          })(marker[i], i));
                          google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'mouseout', (function (markervalue, i) {
                              return function () {
                                  infowindow[i].close();
                              }
                          })(marker[i], i));
                      }
                  })
            }
                </script>
                <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBNKM7U-FRBfd6BfD3UwfRQRRpSgu2TsiU&callback=initMap"
                        async="" defer="defer" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Nikolaus can't retrieve data from database and don't show any markers. there is only a map after calling 'function initMap(zoomeLevel, latDb, longDb)' ,doent work remaining code.

Comment: Do you have any error in Controller, debugging?

Comment: @Nikolaus `ViewBag.ListOfDropdown = db.tb_freeslot.ToList();` returns count of entries in db, ` var data = db.tb_freeslot.ToList();
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` returns all details in table as json format, but `public JsonResult GetAllLocationById(int id)` throws an `argument exception`

Comment: You have SingleOrDefault() in your code. Remove this.

Comment: @Nikolaus don't work

Comment: What's the error and where, if you remove SingleOrDefault()?

Comment: @Nikolaus there is no more error by removing `SingleorDefault()`, but still don't show any markers

Comment: Did you try to debug your callback-function?